# Get randomFloat Fails

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why does my method return values < 0.4 in some cases? 
e.g. 0.225501

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000

float myVar = [self randomFloat:0.4 to:2];


- (float)randomFloat:(int)from to:(int)to
{
    return ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) * (to - from) + from;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are casting your parameters to integers (which in your case changes your range to between 0 and 2), change the parameters to be `float`.

```
- (float)randomFloat:(float)from to:(float)to
```

Answer (score 0):

when dividing and using floats the precision of the decimals is sometimes lost. Maybe you can use a `long` with N fixed number of digits and place the decimal point before those digits. The other day I was getting strange results when adding (1 + (3/10))= should be 1.3 but I always had something like 1.29995 . Hope it helps

Comment: I know it's not a straight answer but when I found about this I was really mad and I what it to share it.